# SPLIT_BUNDLE 3. Action Required : Your app is not compliant with Google Play Policies , what is the solution?

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, flutter-dependencies, android-manifest

I'm not using the  `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission in my Flutter application. But Play Store has removed my application due to this. I have verified this from my manifest file. But also added :
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"/>`

But again google rejects my build. Maybe any Flutter package is using this but I don't know which package is using it.

My pubspec.yaml packges:

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  # image_picker: ^0.8.4+4
  image_picker: ^1.0.4
  http: ^0.13.4
  # shared_preferences: ^2.0.12
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.1
  flutter_bloc: ^8.0.1
  bloc: ^8.0.2
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  # file_picker: ^4.3.3
  file_picker: ^5.5.0
  # open_file: ^3.2.1
  open_filex: ^4.3.2
  syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer: ^19.4.52-beta
```

and my manifest permissions are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"/>
```

Please suggest any solution or help will be highly appreciated as I have wasted my time on this issue.

> Issue found: Permission use is not directly related to your app's core purpose.
> `SPLIT_BUNDLE 3`
>
> Please remove the use of REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission from all version codes within
> the submission. This includes both production and testing tracks.

You can see issue's image [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RBX5KQIBGcTfraRCfBlNsihQSeZV86RX/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please do not post the most important information in an image. In the beginning of your question you reference information and only present in the screen shot hidden at the end of your question...

Answer (score 1):

Open your app's android folder in using android studio. then go to app module. then open the manifest in that module. There you will se 2 tabs on the bottom

[image]

here you will see there is tab named merged manifest. select that. then you will see the resulting manifest after adding all of your dependencies. on right side you can click on certain dependency to see what is has added.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm unable to find this permission in any of the manifests. I have checked the project's as well as the packages' manifest files.

Comment: Try preparing an apk. Then rename the apk to .zip then extract it. See if your extracted folder manifest.xml is your stated permission there or not.